# How to pick out lm regression coefficients without name of variable?

Tags: r, regression, lm

This will be a pretty basic question, but when I type:

```
reg = lm(y ~ x) 
# then call reg,
reg

reg$coefficients
```

I get the two regression parameter estimates.  But I would like to be able to pick them out without getting "(Intercept)" and "Elapsed_Time" attached to them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on a built in data set

```
 # set up the lm object
 carsregcoef <- lm(dist~speed,cars)$coefficients

 # remove names
 names(carsregcoef) <- NULL

 # print it:
 carsregcoef
 [1] -17.579095   3.932409
```

See `?names` for details

You could always write a little function to strip the names. Maybe something like:

```
 unname <- function(x) {
              names(x) <- NULL  
              x
            }
```

Then you could do this sort of thing:

```
carsregcoef <- unname(lm(dist~speed,cars)$coefficients)
```